# What versions of .NET and WPF, does the ModernUI framework support?

Tags: wpf, modern-ui

I'm working with a WPF app that was written using the [ModernUI framework](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui). I'm wondering what versions of the .NET Framework does the ModernUI support?

Comment: the .net framework doesn't support/require modernui. its the other way around.

Comment: Daniel, are you saying that any version of the .NET Framework, will support the ModernUI framework?

Comment: you'll have to ask the author or do some digging on the repo

Comment: The author hasn't answered any questions in the issues, since 2017. I'll see if I can figure it out looking through their code.

Comment: For anyone else who might wonder, according to the Readme.txt file (dated June 11, 2013) it the ModernUI will work up to .NET 4.5. I'm guessing any newer, regular .NET framework will work. Sorry for asking the question, Daniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ModernUI` assemblies target .NET Framework 4.5 which means that the library is compatible with any version equal to or larger than 4.5.

You can confirm this by looking at the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` elements in the `.csproj` files on [GitHub](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/blob/master/1.0/FirstFloor.ModernUI/FirstFloor.ModernUI/FirstFloor.ModernUI.csproj):

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```